# iPhone shows apple logo and iPhone is not restored gives unknown error 2001

Tags: itunes, ios, iphone

my iPhone5 is dropped from my hand when i put from floor than it shows continuously apple logo i attached iPhone with itunes and try to restore after download whole software it gives error The iPhone "iPhone" could not be restored. An unknown error occurred (2001).

please provide me any solution. i'm so much worry about this. thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds to be something is broken on the inside causing this problem, since you dropped the iPhone on the floor.